# Public class variable inaccessible in aspx page VS2017 15.3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net

Just recently I have started getting errors in IntelliSense and during compile time for a public class variable that is being accessed in the aspx page.

Quote_Edit.aspx.cs:

```
public partial class Quote_Edit : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public Quote currentquote;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    }
        currentquote = new Quote(1);
    }
}
```

Quote_Edit.aspx:

```
...
    <h1>Quote Information</h1>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <table class="data-input">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="label">Quote #:</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><%= currentquote.ID %></td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
    </table>
...
```

IntelliSense complains that `The name 'currentquote' does not exist in the current context`. When I use Web Publish, the compiler also complains.

We upgraded to VS 2017 Enterprise from VS 2013 Ultimate and since then we have been seeing these errors pop up sporadically. To get the error to go away temporarily, I can clean the code and rebuild it and that will allow it to be published.

Comment: what is the framework version you are using? Have you changed it?

Comment: 4.5.2. It was recently changed from 4.0 due to some package dependencies being updated.